# Getting errors in executing git commands

Tags: git, github

For removing a folder of the repo from git, the command is

```
git rm -r "folder name"
```

but doing so, I get this error and can't find out why?
Any suggestions, please?

[image: git command for removing folder]

Comment: Please, remove the image and paste the text output.

Answer (score 1):

Try via using -rf instead of -r like :

```
git rm -rf kunal/
```

Comment: It may be because your folder contains the sub-folders and files. So, we use the -rf which is a substitute of -r -f (recursive deleting of folders and files both). And accept the answer if it worked as required.